# spring thymeleaf Sort enum alphbetically

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have an enum:

```
public static enum States {

    SEL("Selangor"),
    WP("Wilayah Persekutuan"),      
    KEL("Kelantan"),
    LAB("Labuan"),
    PER("Perlis");  

    private String value;

    States(String val) {
        this.value = val ;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }       
}
```

The values are displayed on a Thymeleaf template by:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 padding-sides-none">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 padding-sides-none">
    <label class="col-xs-2 padding-sides-none" style="margin-left:15px">State</label>
    <div class="col-xs-7 padding-sides-none">
      <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
              style="width:300px;margin-left: 50px;">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Please select a state</option>
        <option th:each="state : ${T(com.workspez.model.Accountant.States).values()}"
                th:value="${state}" th:text="${state.getValue()}">
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to display the values in alphabetical order. is it possible? One way is to manually arrange the enum but is there any way to sort the enum list?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `comparator` inside States enum to compare and sort enum values like this:

```
public enum States {
    SEL("Selangor"),
    WP("Wilayah Persekutuan"),      
    KEL("Kelantan"),
    LAB("Labuan"),
    PER("Perlis");  

    private String value;       
    States(String val){
        this.value = val ;
    }       
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public static States[] getSortedValue(){
        States[] values = States.values();
        Arrays.sort(values,(s1,s2)->s1.getValue().compareTo(s2.getValue()));
        return values;
    }
}
```

In your thymeleaf HTML just call `getSortedValue`method to get values in ascending order like this:

```
<option th:each="state : ${T(com.crud.example.enums.States).getSortedValue()}"
th:value="${state}" 
th:text="${state.getValue()}">
</option>
```

Comment: ${T(com.workspez.model.Accountant.States.getSortedValue()).values()}

Comment: I did '${T(com.workspez.model.Accountant.States.getSortedValue()).values()}'        and i get org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 53): Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lparen(()' error

Comment: how would get selected value? i tried below and combo box wont get populated

Answer (score 0):

how would one get the selected value in combobox?
I did :

```
<select th:field="*{currentAccountant.state}" class="form-control selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" style="width:300px;margin-left: 50px;"  >
                                      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Please select a state</option>
                                     <option th:each="state : ${T(com.model.Accountant.States).getSortedValue()}"
                                        th:value="${state}" 
                                        th:text="${state.getValue()}">
                                    </option>
                                </select>
```

The values no longer get populated.I removed `th:field="*{currentAccountant.state}"` then it gets populated